# Share app through facebook is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hi in my Application i have option of sharing my application through `Facebook`. So I have added the `Facebook framework` to my project and I have added the bundle id into my `Facebook` and got the App id but the problem is I'm not Unable to share the App its showing like this.

```
An error occurred. Please try again later
```

In my Stimulator is showing like this i don't why it's showing like that. If my device have `Facebook App` its working fine but if it doesn't have the `Facebook App` its showing error like this. Please tell how to resolve this issue.

```
   - (IBAction)share:(id)sender {
     FBLinkShareParams *params = [[FBLinkShareParams alloc] init];
     params.link = [NSURL URLWithString:@"url/"];

// If the Facebook app is installed and we can present the share dialog
 if ([FBDialogs canPresentShareDialogWithParams:params]) {

    // Present share dialog
     [FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithLink:params.link
                                  handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) {
                                      if(error) {
                                          // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
                                          // See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
                                          NSLog(@"Error publishing story: %@", error.description);
                                      } else {
                                          // Success
                                          NSLog(@"result %@", results);
                                      }
                                  }];

    // If the Facebook app is NOT installed and we can't present the share dialog
  } else {
    // FALLBACK: publish just a link using the Feed dialog

    // Put together the dialog parameters
    // Put together the dialog parameters
     NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   @"My appname", @"name",
                                   @"test share.", @"caption",
                                   @"sample.", @"description",
                                   @"myrul", @"link",

                                   nil];

    // Show the feed dialog
      [FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:nil
                                           parameters:params
                                              handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
                                                  if (error) {
                                                      // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
                                                      // See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
                                                      NSLog(@"Error publishing story: %@", error.description);
                                                  } else {
                                                      if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
                                                          // User canceled.
                                                          NSLog(@"User cancelled.");
                                                      } else {
                                                          // Handle the publish feed callback
                                                          NSDictionary *urlParams = [self parseURLParams:[resultURL query]];

                                                          if (![urlParams valueForKey:@"post_id"]) {
                                                              // User canceled.
                                                              NSLog(@"User cancelled.");

                                                          } else {
                                                              // User clicked the Share button
                                                              NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Posted story, id: %@", [urlParams valueForKey:@"post_id"]];
                                                              NSLog(@"result %@", result);
                                                          }
                                                      }
                                                  }
                                              }];

                                       }
                                     }


    - (NSDictionary*)parseURLParams:(NSString *)query {
         NSArray *pairs = [query componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];
         NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
     for (NSString *pair in pairs) {
         NSArray *kv = [pair componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
         NSString *val =
        [kv[1] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        params[kv[0]] = val;
      }
    return params;
   }
```

I have used the above code for its not working please help me how to resolve this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for Share App.

```
-(void)facebook
{

   if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {


        SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];


        SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler myBlock = ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){
            if (result == SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled) {

                NSLog(@"Cancelled");

            }
            else
            {
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Congratulations!" message:@"Successfully posted to facebook Wall." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

                [alert show];

                [Flurry logEvent:@"Share screen - Successfully posted on Facebook"];
            }

            [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];
        };

        controller.completionHandler =myBlock;
       NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@" I am using App for my iPhone. You too can download it from here"];
        [controller setInitialText:str];
        [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:Nil];
    }
    else{
         UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry!"message:@"Please add Facebook account in settings menu" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:Nil otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
          alert.tag=100;
         [alert show];
    }
}
```

For use of **SLComposeViewController**,you have to add ***Social Framework***. It fetch your facebook account from *setting* and you can share your app link through ***SLComposeViewController***. and

if you want to add images or URL to in than :

```
[composeController addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]]; 
[composeController addURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"apple.com"]];
```

Comment: please tell wt this code do and wt is that SLComposeViewController which controller is this

Comment: i have already added facebook id everthing but still its not woriking

Comment: Check my answer again .

Comment: i have added the social framework but its showing error on the SLComposeViewController